# Syscall() vs Call()?

Tags: go, winapi, native

I've been experimenting with Go and Win32, and I found these two variants for calling OS functions (code is abbreviated):

```
modUser32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
procMessageBox = modUser32.NewProc("MessageBoxW")

// 1st variant
syscall.Syscall6(procMessageBox.Addr(), 4,
    uintptr(hwnd), toUtf16(msg), toUtf16(caption), uintptr(flags),
    0, 0)

// 2nd variant
procMessageBox.Call(uintptr(hwnd), uintptr(hwnd),
    toUtf16(msg), toUtf16(caption), uintptr(flags))
```

2nd variant is obviously simpler, but are there any disadvantages to it?

Answer (score 0):

They basically don't make much difference, `Syscall` may just be a layer of encapsulation for the `Call`. Both variants have a limit on the number of parameters.

```
syscall.Syscall
syscall.Syscall6
syscall.Syscall9
syscall.Syscall12
syscall.Syscall15
```

Corresponding to parameters <= 3/6/9/12/15.

`Call()` method has up to 15 parameters.